# Is there a way to compile code on a Mac in a sandbox so it doesn't potentially affect my system if something goes wrong?

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg, sandbox

I'm going to attempt to build ffmpeg with a bunch of libraries included and I would like to keep my current system clean in case it all goes to shit. Is there a way to compile programs like ffmpeg so that they don't affect the system if something goes wrong?

I'm a beginner at this stuff, so if this question is misguided and there is no danger in compiling programs please let me know :)

Comment: I really don't think there's any danger of messing up your system by *compiling* a program. Even if there's a trojan embedded in the code that you compile, it will only infect your system when you *execute* the compiled code, not merely when you compile it. There's no cause for concern here: play around as you wish!

Answer (score 0):

I went through a same feeling of organizational OCD/fear when I first started compiling programs from source. The only thing you'll have to worry about (from my experience) is libraries colliding with any kind of package manager that tries to install/symlink to the same location. Most managers give a good warning about pre-existing library collisions though. You can also uninstall self-compiled software/libraries with the `make uninstall` command when you don't want them around anymore.

If you're on OSX I found that using a package manager (homebrew for OSX rocks) was the easiest way to compile FFMPEG including dependancies.

Comment: I'm thinking of trying homebrew. I tried building ffmpeg with libfaac, libx264, and libspeex and I can't get it to build correctly =( Also, if I deleted the source files for the compiled stuff, do I just download it again and then run make uninstall?

Comment: Well, I would do it via homebrew and then work through the inevitable errors it will spit at you when it tries to build ffmpeg for you. You'll have to delete all the pre-existing stuff (from your earlier attempt), but at least homebrew will tell you something like "make sure the file doesn't already exist in ~/foo/bar and then you can just delete it, rinse, repeat.

After the initial install of homebrew make sure to run `brew doctor` and clear up any complaints it has before installing ffmpeg.

Comment: It looks like some of the libraries I need aren't in homebrew :(